# MVC textbox readonly not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtId", new { @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

But it's not working. wHY?

Comment: What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: @asawyer <input id="txtId" name="txtId" type="text" value="{ readonly = true }" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtId", null, new { @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

This is the correct code. Second parameter specifies value for the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtId", new { @readonly = "true" })%>
```

edit: better use TextBoxFor with a typed model:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { @readonly = "true" })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtId", "", new { @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

(second parameter is the value and the third represents the HTML attributes )

The problem in your code is that the `new { @readonly = "readonly" }` object is interpreted as being the value to display in the textbox

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the second parameter. What attribute of the model do you want to bind to this textbox. This should be the second parameter.

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.Attr, new { @readonly="readonly" })%>
```

Of if you don't want to bind to your model use null as the second attribute:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", null, new { @readonly="readonly" })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes should be the 3rd param.

```
TextBox('ID', 'value', 'attributes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtId", string.Empty ,new { @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I realized that the data type of the displayed value must be of a string.
so I converted the model.SOME_DATE from DateTime to string, and the code worked just fine.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SOME_DATE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true } })
```